# FileNotFoundException when converting image to base64 kotlin

Tags: java, spring, kotlin

I have a few images in folders that I want to send back to the user. To do that, I convert the images to base64 and just display them in the front-end. This works for most of the images, but for some reason I get a FileNotFound exception with this one image below.

Code: get the jobs, which contains information and a company object in it. Converting the job images works fine, but when I add the conversion for the company logo it says FileNotFound.

```
@GetMapping
fun getAllJobs(): ResponseEntity<*> {
    return try {
        val jobList: List<Job> = jobRepository.findAll()

        jobList.map {
            val file =  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File("images/job/"+it.jobImage))
            val companyFile =  FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(File("images/company/"+it.company.logo))
            it.company.logo = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(companyFile)
            it.jobImage = "data:image/jpeg;base64,"+Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(file)
        }

        JsonDataResponse(HttpStatus.OK, "Retrieved lists of jobs ", jobList).createResponseEntity()
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        JsonResponse(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, e.message.toString()).createResponseEntity()
    }
}
```

The images folder:

[image]

When I debug and I see what the map is doing, this is the first state of the job object, the logo and jobimage are just references:

[image]

After the first iteration, the images are correctly converted in both objects:

[image]

After the second iteration, I'm getting this error:
[image]

Comment: The exception stacktrace would be useful ...

Comment: java.io.FileNotFoundException: File 'images\company\data:image\jpeg;base64,\9j\4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD..........AXAAAAAUAAAAAAAAH\Z' does not exist
 at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.openInputStream(FileUtils.java:297) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
 at org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(FileUtils.java:1851) ~[commons-io-2.6.jar:2.6]
 at com.example.bouwershub.controllers.JobController.getAllJobs(JobController.kt:34) ~[classes/:na]
 at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
 at ....

Comment: the stacktrace is big, but it is pointing to "val companyFile = FileUtils" in the above code, and that the fiel does not exist, but it does thats why i am confused

Comment: Can you print `"images/company/"+it.company.logo` for a file that you say works fine? Because it looks really strange that you try to read a file with base64.

Comment: Before conversion: images/company/user_2_2021-06-24_logo.png
After setting new value: images/company/data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD......

in the above pictures you can also see the output

Comment: And that is fine, but your stacktrace says what the problem is, you're trying to read a file where the filename is just base64, not the actual name.  The issue is now either `Job` which has static elements or `jobRepository` which doesn't read from a database, but actually from a local collection or something and always returns the same collection.

Comment: It is also a rather error prone design to have properties which contain different types of data. So instead of using `jobImage` to contain the filename and the base64 data, you should think about splitting that to two properties, one for the filename and one for the base64. This can also fix your issue here, but you have a different issue which causes this problem in the first place. So you should try to fix that first and then split the properties.

Comment: JobRepository is getting from the database and i think Job is not static. What i don't quite understand is when i remove the "val companyFile = FileUtils" line the it/jobImage conversion works. and also it only crashes after the second iteration, the first one works how i expect it to

Comment: When the second one fails, then you have either static components in your model class (would be `companion object` in Kotlin) or the repository doesn't read all from the database. You're mutating your `Job` instances in that mapping function. That would be fine if each `Job` instance is completely independent from each other, but they aren't so one instance mutates itself by replacing the filename with base64 and the next instance already got its filename replaced but it treats it like a filename, thus FileNotFoundException. I guess `company` inside `Job` is the problem.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will be working on that now!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234474/discussion-between-mm-da-and-tom).

Comment: @Tom could you help me understand one more thing in the chat room, if you have time?